# How do i learn something like this? (Apple Watch)

Tags: modeling

I want to learn product modelling like attached in the image below. Kindly guide me from where I can learn something like this in Blender. Youtube videos are not very helpful, they are abstract. I want to learn professional methodology of creating quad based product models.

[image]

[image]

They are all from the same image set. It looks so perfect!

Comment: Hello, your question is a bit too broad, and I'm not sure why you're not glad with the youtube tutorials, you can learn everything with youtube only, including this kind of objects

Comment: this has been asked multiple times before and there are answers here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: @moonboots There are couple of Apple Watch modelling videos but none of them are accurate. They're all just random look alike watch and doesn't do the intricate details of the model as shown here. It may seem simple but it isn't , atleast not for me.

Comment: maybe, but Blender Stack Exchange is not made for such a complicated question that would need a long answer, maybe tell one particular obstacle you're fighting with?

Comment: I think you should give up on hoping there is someone doing exactly what you need in the exact quality or skill level you want on a specific object. I know for myself Blender can be difficult to learn, but you won't get around it if you ever want to do complex objects yourself. I've learned very much from tutorials, and I've watched many even dealing with things I didn't need (at least not in that moment). With this and trying out things for yourself you will get the skills you need. If you need the object right now, maybe you should rather buy a model.

Comment: Sorry, don't mean to be offensive, it's just how it is. You see I've been using Blender for so many years now, but there's always something to learn (especially when things are changed over time and new features are implemented)... and nowadays I watch tutorials and are amazed by some cool things the tutor does on the one hand and shake my head about how complicated he does something else which I know how to do much easier. Nobody can fully teach you everything and even then you might be more comfortable with different workflows or methods for certain things.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I am not offended. But, I want to learn. Of course I can make this model myself, in fact I already have but, it is not accurate. It is more of makeshift model, where I used random techniques to make the model. But such effort always has limitation. I want to learn, make perfect models that can be zoomed in and no one could tell the difference between the real thing and 3D model. *Cheers*

Comment: But when you already have modeled it, you could ask about specific things you are not happy with. This question is a general "how do I do this?" which requires more of a tutorial or guide as you call it. If your goal is to get from building a good topology model to having a photorealistic render, there are many, many very different steps inbetween. This is not what this site is for. And if you are not happy with the tutorials you watched and want us to name others - do you have a list which ones we should not suggest...? Or do you simply want us to find one for you doing exactly this model?